# Nested list inside list - Drag Drop - Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying for a while to implement nested tree of drag-drop element which can be drag from place to place at the tree.

I was trying some idea's, like recursive tree, but at the end point the result is that it's impossible to make one list inside another and make them all aware to each other .

It's one example that I took an example that I've saw here and have tried to design it for my needs, 
but as you can see the subs lists don't interact with other sub-lists.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-connected-lists-s9yneu

The original code was : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-connected-lists

(sorry for credit doesn't remember the question )

I have also found this solution which implemented with mat-tree and very complex functionality :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tree-with-drag-and-drop?file=app%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.html

So my question is - is there is not simple way to implement nested drag-drop functionality by Angular material drag-drop ?

Comment: You already made it work so what's the problem? Angular provides some examples here https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview but none of them are nested lists.

Comment: The problem is that the subs list don't interact with other subs... 
As you said - no example is of nested list . @tobias

Comment: the only thing you need is that each element was a cdkDropList and put all the elements in a cdkDropListGroup

Comment: @Eliseo with nested drop-lists (inside cdg drag elements) - it won't work
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14093

Known problem